# Determine third point of Right Triangle when two points and all sides are known and $A\hat BC=90$

Tags: triangles

I have two points and all sides of right triangle

[I need find A point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muqt2.jpg)

\begin{gather*}
|AB| = 1 \\
|BC| = 1 \\
|AC| = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt2 \\
A(?,?) \\
B(0,0) \\
C(1,0) \\
 \\
|AB| = 1 \\
|BC| = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt2 \\
|AC| = \sqrt{1^2 + \sqrt2^2} = \sqrt3 \\
A(?,?) \\
B(0,0) \\
C(1,0)
\end{gather*}

The angle in $B$ is 90 degrees.

I need a formula to find point $A$. 
i need infinity loop that create a chain of triangle not just one  triangle

Comment: $|BC|=\sqrt2$ and $B(0,0),C(1,0)$ are in contradiction since $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ are evidently 1 apart, not $\sqrt2$ apart. If I follow the picture, the answer to the first set of equations is terribly obvious: $A(0,1)$. And all you need is the positions of $B,C$, the angle $A\hat BC=90$ and $|AB|=1$, without the other lengths. Of course, $A(0,-1)$ would be equally fine with just sides and angles, but then the picture rules $A(0,-1)$ out, right?

Comment: @fleablood this was more or less my reaction too :).

Comment: I'm sorry.  It was rude.

Comment: I will now add the square roots I twice forgot to add :).

Comment: The suggestion to make a drawing was a good point though. Perhaps you should have removed the "LOOK" part and left the rest of the comment :).